Windows Server - RDP re-login - Many processes get restarted
Problem:
Windows Server 2022 - On a RDP Session a Java Application is started - when I close the RDP session (but not logging off) and than re logging in the Java Application is closed. The Windows Log shows that many process get terminated (4689) and than restarted immediately (4688) but not this application it just gets terminated. How can I further debug this problem or could anybody already imagine a reason?
Regards
Erik
